# Mercurial browser on Windows 2003 takes several refreshes before displaying repositories

Tags: windows-server-2003, mercurial, isapi

When attempt to browse my Mercurial repositories it usually takes several refreshes before the repository list is displayed. The configuration is as follows:

- Windows Server 2003 (Dedicated machine hosted by http://www.server4you.com/.
- Site has anonymous password protection with self-signed SSL.
- Mercurial 1.5.3
- Python 2.6.5
- Python for Windows 32 extensions 214 py2.6
- isapi-wsgi 0.4.2

The repositories are being served via ISAPI using the standard hgwebdir_wspi.py file (copy to follow).

Also before doing a clone/push/etc I have to browse the repositories first otherwise hg on my local machine can not locate the site.

What can I do to start tracking down this problem?

**hgwebdir_wsgi.py**

```
# Configuration file location
hgweb_config = r'C:\Public\Mercurial\WebSite\hgweb.config'

# Global settings for IIS path translation
path_strip = 0   # Strip this many path elements off (when using url rewrite)
path_prefix = 0  # This many path elements are prefixes (depends on the
                 # virtual path of the IIS application).

import sys

# Adjust python path if this is not a system-wide install
#sys.path.insert(0, r'c:\path\to\python\lib')

# Enable tracing. Run 'python -m win32traceutil' to debug
if hasattr(sys, 'isapidllhandle'):
    import win32traceutil

# To serve pages in local charset instead of UTF-8, remove the two lines below
import os
os.environ['HGENCODING'] = 'UTF-8'


import isapi_wsgi
from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
from mercurial.hgweb.hgwebdir_mod import hgwebdir

# Example tweak: Replace isapi_wsgi's handler to provide better error message
# Other stuff could also be done here, like logging errors etc.
class WsgiHandler(isapi_wsgi.IsapiWsgiHandler):
    error_status = '500 Internal Server Error' # less silly error message

isapi_wsgi.IsapiWsgiHandler = WsgiHandler

# Only create the hgwebdir instance once
application = hgwebdir(hgweb_config)

def handler(environ, start_response):

    # Translate IIS's weird URLs
    url = environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] + environ['PATH_INFO']
    paths = url[1:].split('/')[path_strip:]
    script_name = '/' + '/'.join(paths[:path_prefix])
    path_info = '/'.join(paths[path_prefix:])
    if path_info:
        path_info = '/' + path_info
    environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = script_name
    environ['PATH_INFO'] = path_info

    return application(environ, start_response)

def __ExtensionFactory__():
    return isapi_wsgi.ISAPISimpleHandler(handler)

if __name__=='__main__':
    from isapi.install import *
    params = ISAPIParameters()
    HandleCommandLine(params)
```

**hgweb.config**

```
[paths]
/ = C:\Public\Mercurial\Repositories\*

[web]
allow_archive = bz2 gz zip      ; Allows archive downloads.
allow_push = ########       ; Users that are allowed to push.
```

Comment: The behavior you describe is strange... I've never seen Mercurial behave like that. I've asked people on G+ if they can help. If I were you, then I would write mercurial@selenic.com to see if there's someone there that can help debug this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like IIS 6 is caching your web pages (you didn't define if you were using Apache or not, so I assumed as it's a Windows server)

Use this [link from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx?mfr=true) and set the site to **Expire Immediately**.

Answer (score 0):

Something caches on the way. Use curl or wget to get the page and check the http headers. Is it better without ssl?